# Importing javascript function into Typescript file: function is seen as namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to import a plain javascript function into a typescript file. I'm working on a React Native app.

The import is working when its just JS, but on TS I get the error: `Cannot use namespace 'PrimaryButton' as a type`

The javascript function resides in a node module which exports its function as such in its index.js:

`export {default as PrimaryButton} from './src/components/PrimaryButton.js';`

The node module is called `component-library`, it is a company own node module. It does not contain any types at all, only plain JS.

I have included a `custom.d.ts` file in the RN app where I declare `component-library` as a module to avoid TS errors on import:

`declare module 'component-library';`

Now, when trying to import the PrimaryButton function, I get the error `Cannot use namespace 'PrimaryButton' as a type`.

What is the easiest way to enable to import of the PrimaryButton function without errors? I'm pretty new to Typescript and kind of lost here.

Comment: What does `PrimaryButton.js` look like? Specifically the part exporting the function you're trying to import?

Comment: It's a default function export:
`export default function PrimaryButton(props) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up being something really simple... The file had the .ts extension instead of .tsx, so when using the tsx syntax it was detected as a type instead because of the `<Component>` notation.